# Dynamic dates queries in SQL

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have a big dataset and I want to make it shorter in order to make it easier for Power BI to read. What I need is to get data for only 6 months having my date variable as FechaCarga in MyTable, which is refreshed daily and has daily data.

Example:

```sql
select *
from Mytable
where FechaCarga between   (
    select max(FechaCarga)
    from MyTable) 
and 
--THIS IS THE PART THAT IM MISSING, PROBABLY USING DATEADD.
```

I expect data from Today (MaxDate) and MaxDate - 6 months. Please help me.

Thanks in advance,

IC

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(fechacarga) over () as max_fechacarga
      from mytable t
     ) t
where fechacarga > dateadd(month, -6, max_fechacarga);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, just use DATEADD(). Try `current_date` to get today's date. (not sure if all DBMS's support that)

```
select *
from Mytable
where
    FechaCarga between
       (select max(FechaCarga) from MyTable)
        and dateadd(month, -6, current_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way since you are always looking until the max date is:

```
select *
from Mytable
where FechaCarga >= dateadd(month, -6, (select max(FechaCarga) from MyTable))
```